# How to delete column from pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my pandas Dataframe:

```
file,class,type,cbo,wmc,dit,rfc,lcom,totalMethods,staticMethods,publicMethods,privateMethods,protectedMethods,defaultMethods,abstractMethods,finalMethods,synchronizedMethods,totalFields,staticFields,publicFields,privateFields,protectedFields,defaultFields,finalFields,synchronizedFields,nosi,loc,returnQty,loopQty,comparisonsQty,tryCatchQty,parenthesizedExpsQty,stringLiteralsQty,numbersQty,assignmentsQty,mathOperationsQty,variablesQty,maxNestedBlocks,anonymousClassesQty,subClassesQty,lambdasQty,uniqueWordsQty
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Block.java,blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Block,class,2,40,1,16,14,17,0,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,159,18,9,0,0,5,4,45,50,8,8,28,2,0,0,0,61
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\BlockFactory.java,blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.BlockFactory,class,3,22,1,23,231,22,22,1,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,224,22,0,0,0,0,0,199,43,0,0,43,0,0,0,0,33
```

I need to delete the column file and type. 
I used this code.

```
Import pandas as pd 
import csv 
df=pd.read_csv('class.csv', sep=',')
df=drop(['file','type'])
```

It return for me this

```
        class   cbo wmc dit rfc lcom    totalMethods    staticMethods   publicMethods   privateMethods  protectedMethods    defaultMethods  abstractMethods finalMethods    synchronizedMethods totalFields staticFields    publicFields    privateFields   protectedFields defaultFields   finalFields synchronizedFields  nosi    loc returnQty   loopQty comparisonsQty  tryCatchQty parenthesizedExpsQty    stringLiteralsQty   numbersQty  assignmentsQty  mathOperationsQty   variablesQty    maxNestedBlocks anonymousClassesQty subClassesQty   lambdasQty  uniqueWordsQty
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\Block.java    class   40  1   16  14  17  0   17  0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   159 18  9   0   0   5   4   45  50  8   8   28  2   0   0   0   61
C:\BlokusDuo-master\app\src\main\java\blokusgame\mi\android\hazi\blokus\GameLogic\BlockFactory.java class   22  1   23  231 22  22  1   21  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   21  224 22  0   0   0   0   0   199 43  0   0   43  0   0   0   0   33
```

It delete just file and type from the head but their values still. I also used del df['column_name']!

Any help please!

Comment: `del df['file']`, `del df['type']`

Comment: As far as I can see, type is deleted. File is probably your index?

Comment: the type is class  it's not deleted and the file is the name of classes

Comment: @ilja I tried it but it's not working !

Comment: In your second df, after df=drop..., the column with ‘2’ and ‘3’ (right after ‘class’) is missing/deleted. Are your column labels correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip that column using **usecols**

```
Import pandas as pd 
import csv

df = pd.read_csv(
      "class.csv", 
      usecols = lambda column : column not in ["class","type"],
      index=False, sep=","
    )
```

[source1](https://honingds.com/blog/pandas-read_csv/)

[source2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thnaks but it delete the just the type I think the other column is an index so do u have solution to delete index

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.drop(['file','type'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added one line into your code to get the desired solution.

```
df=pd.read_csv('class.csv', sep=',')
df.drop(['file','type'], axis=1, inplace=True)  
# axis=1 for column AND inplace=True will make changes in df.
df
```

I hope  it may help you.